# Correcting Clock Drift in Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time, time-series

Firstly, I apologise for the naming of this request – I'm a little unsure of exactly what the technique is labeled. I will try to explain as best as I can.

I have loggers in the field collecting environmental data. Their internal clock is synced to the ‘real time’ before been placed in the field. However, the internal clock begins drifting away from the real time throughout its operational life. For example, after a year in the field the data file still reports logging on the hour (at say, 20:00:00), but the real time may be 20:07. The loggers often operate multiple years, and the log rate can range  between 1 minute to 4 hours (though always the same log rate within one file).
I've previously been using software that accomplished this sync internally. I'm now using software that unfortunately does not contain sucha  feature; it does however have an API which will allows the use of python to 'pre-processing' work before appending to the existing dataset.

The goal is to 'stretch' or 'lag' or more generally, align the time so that the last log equals the 'true time'. A simple example:

Original:

```
Datetime,Value
24/03/2018 10:00:00,25.966
24/03/2018 11:00:00,27.402
24/03/2018 12:00:00,29.137
24/03/2018 13:00:00,32.001
24/03/2018 14:00:00,33.661
24/03/2018 15:00:00,34.852
24/03/2018 16:00:00,34.252
24/03/2018 17:00:00,31.605
24/03/2018 18:00:00,30.033
24/03/2018 19:00:00,27.790
24/03/2018 20:00:00,26.214
```

To Become:

```
Datetime,Value
24/03/2018 10:00:00,25.966
24/03/2018 11:00:42,27.402
24/03/2018 12:01:24,29.137
24/03/2018 13:02:06,32.001
24/03/2018 14:02:48,33.661
24/03/2018 15:03:30,34.852
24/03/2018 16:04:12,34.252
24/03/2018 17:04:54,31.605
24/03/2018 18:05:36,30.033
24/03/2018 19:06:18,27.790
24/03/2018 20:07:00,26.214
```

What methods exists to sync/align the data? Does it require resampling? Or is there a much simpler method to achieve this?

The datetime and values

```
df = {'2018-03-24 10:00:00': {'Value': 25.966}, '2018-03-24 11:00:00': {'Value': 27.402},'2018-03-24 12:00:00': {'Value': 29.137}, '2018-03-24 13:00:00': {'Value': 32.001},'2018-03-24 14:00:00': {'Value': 33.661}, '2018-03-24 15:00:00': {'Value': 34.852},'2018-03-24 16:00:00': {'Value': 34.252}, '2018-03-24 17:00:00': {'Value': 31.605},'2018-03-24 18:00:00': {'Value': 30.033}, '2018-03-24 19:00:00': {'Value': 27.790},'2018-03-24 20:00:00': {'Value': 26.214}}
```

Any help, or even suggestions for what direction to look in would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: There are two steps to this. The first one is correcting the observation times according to the boundary conditions. You seem to have already solved that above (manually?). The second one is resampling, which is only needed if you require the observation times to be equal between all the sensors. Is that a requirement you have? If not, I wouldn't bother with resampling as it introduces a kind of guesswork (for lack of a better word) and is dependent on filter choice, etc.

Comment: Sensors are not required to be equal; they are downloaded in the field at different times. However the 'To Become' list was just done manually; I'm not actually sure how to achieve this using python. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I see. I've provided a function below I wrote earlier that does that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (the typecasting of `start` and `end` could use some improvement as it is a little clunky, but it works):

```py
def dedrift(df, start=None, end=None):
    epochs = pd.to_datetime(df.index).astype(int) 
    first = pd.to_datetime(start).to_datetime64().astype(int) if start is not None else epochs[0] 
    last = pd.to_datetime(end).to_datetime64().astype(int) if end is not None else epochs[-1] 
    interval = (last - first)//(len(df) - 1) 
    df['dedrifted'] = pd.to_datetime(range(first, last+1, interval)) 
    return df
```

It calculates the timespan (in nanoseconds) between start and finish and replaces either endpoint with known times to create a new regularly spaced time series. Note that this depends on your stated assumption "always the same log rate within one file". An irregularly sampled data set would require a different approach.

You can use `start` and/or `end` to provide the known boundary conditions (e.g., exact time of install or removal of the sensor):

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'2018-03-24 10:00:00': {'Value': 25.966}, '2018-03-24 11:00:00': {'Value': 27.402},'2018-03-24 12:00:00': {'Value': 29.137}, '2018-03-24 13:00:00': {'Value': 32.001},'2018-03-24 14:00:00': {'Value': 33.661}, '2018-03-24 15:00:00': {'Value': 34.852},'2018-03-24 16:00:00': {'Value': 34.252}, '2018-03-24 17:00:00': {'Value': 31.605},'2018-03-24 18:00:00': {'Value': 30.033}, '2018-03-24 19:00:00': {'Value': 27.790},'2018-03-24 20:00:00': {'Value': 26.214}}).T
>>> dedrift(df, end='2018-03-24 20:07:00')
                      Value           dedrifted
2018-03-24 10:00:00  25.966 2018-03-24 10:00:00
2018-03-24 11:00:00  27.402 2018-03-24 11:00:42
2018-03-24 12:00:00  29.137 2018-03-24 12:01:24
2018-03-24 13:00:00  32.001 2018-03-24 13:02:06
2018-03-24 14:00:00  33.661 2018-03-24 14:02:48
2018-03-24 15:00:00  34.852 2018-03-24 15:03:30
2018-03-24 16:00:00  34.252 2018-03-24 16:04:12
2018-03-24 17:00:00  31.605 2018-03-24 17:04:54
2018-03-24 18:00:00  30.033 2018-03-24 18:05:36
2018-03-24 19:00:00  27.790 2018-03-24 19:06:18
2018-03-24 20:00:00  26.214 2018-03-24 20:07:00
```

Comment: Thanks! I've copied your example over exactly, however I get the error 'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index'.

Comment: Oops sorry, somehow the `pd.RangeIndex` created an index of length 10 whereas a Python `range` with the same parameters had length 11. It should work now.

Comment: I have a similar problem, however I do not have a 'true' start and end time (in fact, the "loggers" started/ended data collection at slightly different times), and the sampling is irregular (determined by environmental noise). How might one approach such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sebs answer really helped with the concept, but I just unable get it to work without errors.

I ended up using something a little different (but used the ideas from Sebs answer). Time is synced when logger installed, so it was fine for me to anchor that.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=sRow, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, usecols=[cols for cols in range(5)])

def TimeAlign(df):
    logStart = df.index[0]
    logEnd = df.index[-1]
    logNum = len(df)
    logFreq = pd.Timedelta(df.index[1] - df.index[0])
    logDiff = pd.Timedelta(pd.to_datetime(input("Enter real time of last log (e.g 01/01/2020 10:07):")) - logEnd)
    logDrift = pd.Timedelta(logDiff / (logNum -1) + logFreq)

    df.index = pd.date_range(start=logStart, periods=logNum, freq=logDrift)
    df.index = df.index.round('1s')

    df.to_csv('TimeAlign.csv', float_format='%.3f' )

    return df

TimeAlign(df)
```